# how can you remove the default hover effect with MenuItem Mui class

Tags: javascript, material-ui

im trying to remove the default gray hover over animation with MUI menu item class ..

here are some examples that ive tried that Dont work.

```
<MenuItem divider sx={{'&:hover':{backgroundColor:'white'}}}>{`${selectedObj.tag.name}`}</MenuItem>
```

```
<MenuItem divider sx={{'&:hover':'none'}}>{`${selectedObj.tag.name}`}</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work with MUI version `5.10.16`

```
<MenuItem divider sx={{ '&:hover': { backgroundColor: 'white' } }}>
      Hover me
</MenuItem>
```

Check this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8kgg6j-j9dmne?file=demo.tsx)

Comment: thats what i thought.. but maybe its the version ill check that.

Comment: changing the version did not help i wonder what else would cause an override on the styles, or sx prop rather?

Comment: ah ok i figured it out. it was a specific item that i was changing styles too i just had to add it to the other items. thanks Anjan!